# Emberjs Displaying the actual route href="" to increase site browsability

Tags: seo, ember.js, browsable

I have re-designed and deployed our commercial site using 100% Ember using pushState to increase the search engines capability to browse the site content.

But, I have one issue that I am not sure how to solve. I am using "actions" to redirect to Ember App routes.

As an example, here an "a" tag:

```
<a {{action "doSales"}} title="Sales and after sales services">Sales and after sales services</a>
```

The associated action:

```
doSales: function(router, event) {
    router.transitionTo('sales');
},
```

And the route:

```
sales: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/:locale/sales',
```

**But**, in the DOM, the final a tag will look like:

```
<a data-ember-action="9" title="Sales and after sales services">Sales and after sales services</a>
```

As you can see there's no **href="/en/sales"**

Which means that if I ask a browser to browse my site, it won't be able to dig down the site structure.

Does anyone knows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action href support was removed with the new router. 
If you want href's on your anchor tags, you will either need to move to using the `{{#linkTo}}` helper (which generates them automatically) or add in the href values manually.

Comment: Excellent. I'll give a shot to this. I was focus on previous release and didn't catch up with the new versions. Will try and come back for feedback. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It does what I was needing it to. But a huge load of modifications to rewrite my router.